# Read bytebuffer from specific area on the screen

Tags: opengl, jogl, glreadpixels

I'm trying to read the pixeldata from multiple predefined squares on the screen. However for some reason the bytebuffer that gets returned is the same for whichever square I choose.

This is the function I'm using:

```
private void loadByteBuffer()
{
    int                 width   = (bounds[2] - bounds[0]);
    int                 height  = (bounds[3] - bounds[1]);

    GLReadBufferUtil    util    = new GLReadBufferUtil(false, true);
                        util.readPixels(gl, bounds[0], bounds[1], width, height, false);
    TextureData         texData = util.getTextureData();

    byteBuffer = (ByteBuffer) texData.getBuffer();
    util.dispose(gl);
    texData.destroy();
}
```

is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not surprising... given the code you have shown, one can assume that `bounds` is constant. It should probably be a parameter in the function.

Comment: My bad, I should have elaborated a bit more. this method is part of a class of which multiple instances exist. Each instance has it's own values for bounds.